# Build resource assemblies with AssemblyBuilder

Tags: c#, dynamic, resources, .net-assembly

Scenario: I want to create satellite assemblies which are resource assemblies. 
          This assembly has only compiled resources in it (ResourceWriter). 
          **The goal is to create resource assemblies outside of VS and add them to the application and this in my C# application**

Atm I´m using AssemblyBuilder to create the Assembly. It works but there is no information about the assembly stored. No cultureinfo, key or anything else. The assembly isn´t taken by the app with an Missing Manfifest Resource Exception. :(

If possible i want to stay with AssemblyBuilder or using CodeDomProvider.

**Question**: What is necessary to be able to add new satelite assembly to my app? Is it enough to have a folder with the culture (en-US) and an assembly with the en-US resources in there?

**Question2**: Is it possible to give some meta information like Version, Culture to the assembly?

**Question3**: Is ist enough to add the resources to the assembly?

Code:

```
AssemblyBuilder builder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
                        assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave, resourceFolder);

builder.AddResourceFile(name, assemblyFileName);
builder.Save(assemblyName.Name);
```

For any kind of help i would be grateful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution.

Source: http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/58/290731.aspx

Explanation: First It seems the **AssemblyBuilder only link the resource to the assembly**, its not embedded. Second the resource has to be in **Module** to be seen by the main assembly. 
(I dislike to crate the Resource within the module but there seems to be no way to embedded already existing resource)

the Code:

```
        string myAsmName = "WriteSatelliteAssembly.resources";
        string myAsmFileName = myAsmName + ".dll";
        string resourceName = "WriteSatelliteAssembly.MyResource2.fr.resources";
        string path;

        path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "fr-FR";
        AppDomain appDomain = Thread.GetDomain();
        AssemblyName asmName = new AssemblyName();
        asmName.Name = myAsmName;
        asmName.CodeBase = path;
        asmName.CultureInfo = new CultureInfo("fr");

        AssemblyBuilder myAsmBuilder = appDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            asmName,
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave, path);

        **ModuleBuilder** myModuleBuilder =
            myAsmBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(myAsmFileName,
            myAsmFileName);
        **IResourceWriter** rw =
            myModuleBuilder.DefineResource(resourceName,
            "My Description",ResourceAttributes.Public);

        rw.AddResource("resName","My (dynamic) resource value.");
        rw.AddResource("resName2","My (dynamic) second resource value.");

        myAsmBuilder.Save(myAsmFileName);
```

**Proof shortend:**

Linked resource in assembly

```
.file nometadata 'TestProjectResourceManager.Properties.Resources.en-US.resources'
    .hash = (57 DD 82 37 9E B3 BA 8A 27 D0 69 90 37 67 22 23   // W..7....'.i.7g"#
             A0 1C F7 47 )                                     // ...G
.mresource public TestProjectResourceManager.Properties.Resources
{
  .file 'TestProjectResourceManager.Properties.Resources.en-US.resources' at 0x00000000
}
```

embedded resource in assembly

```
.mresource public 'TestProjectResourceManager.Properties.Resources.en-US.resources'
{
  // Offset: 0x00000000 Length: 0x000000EE
}
.module TestProjectResourceManager_2.resources.dll
```

Have fun

Comment: I will check it in free time , upvoted your efforts to share ;)

Comment: Also you can accept your answer as well if you think this is what you were really after.

Answer (score 3):

You will need the following tools to create assemblies.

1. resgen.exe
2. al.exe
3. ildasm.exe

al.exe is the program that embeds resources into a satellite assembly. But al.exe will only accept resources in .resources binary format. But our inputs are usually either plain text resource files or XML-based resource files in .resx format. resgen.exe is used to convert these alternate forms of resources to the .resources binary format palatable to al.exe.

ildasm.exe: If you remember what Visual Studio IDE is doing, you will see that there is a name translation between your resource file directory structure and how that resource file is known inside of the assembly. Becaue we are using the Visual Studio IDE to generate the default resources and the extenal process to generate the satellite assemblies, both mechanisms must produce assemblies with the same kind of naming hierarchy for the resource files.

So we use ildasm to examine the DLLs that Visual Studio IDE generates to find out what the structure is, and use the same mechanism to generate the satellite assemblies. You can also examine the satellite assemblies using ildasm to make sure that you get the names right. This will be useful for debugging errors from the resource manager telling you that it can not locate a resource.

Now that the tools are outlined, how do we convert an external resource file into a satellite assembly? As noted below, this is a three (really, two) step process.

Step 0: Set your paths for resgen and al.exe:

```
@set path=%path%;
    "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET\FrameworkSDK\Bin";
     c:\winnt\microsoft.NET\framework\v1.0.3705
```

Step 1: Use resgen to create a .resources file from a .resx file.

```
Resgen MyText.resx
```

The above command will create a file called:

```
MyText.resources
```

Step 2: Use al.exe to create the satellite assembly:

```
Al.exe
     /t:lib
     /embed:MyText.en-gb.Resources,MyApplication.MyText.en-gb.Resources
     /culture:hi-gb
     /out:MyApplication.resources.dll
```

There are a couple of things worth noting here:

```
/t:lib: Says you are interested in a .dll.

/embed:MyText.en-gb.Resources,MyApplication.MyText.en-gb.Resources : Embeds and renames the resource to a target name to match the Visual Studio IDE naming structure.

/culture:hi-gb : Identifies the culture in which you are interested.

/out:MyApplication.resources.dll : Name of the DLL in which you are interested.
```

The generated .dll has to have that naming convention for .NET to find it. Also notice that you have to specify the culture setting, even though the culture is available in the name of the resource files. So it has to be mentioned in both places.

Place the Satellite Assembly in the Appropriate Directory
Once the satellite assembly is created, physically copy the .dll to the following directory:

```
\MyApplication\bin\en-gb\MyApplication.Resources.DLL
```

In case of multiple resource files:

```
\MyApplication\resources\files\CommonResources.resx
\MyApplication\resources\files\Module1Resources.resx
\MyApplication\resources\files\Module2Resources.resx
```

And you can define keys for these resources in a separate hierarchy, as follows:

```
\MyApplication\resources\keys\CommonKeys.cs
\MyApplication\resources\keysModule1Keys.cs
\MyApplication\resources\keys\Module2Keys.cs
```

---

For a batch program script, please refer to my blog
http://samithenerd.blogspot.com/2011/12/batch-program-for-creating-satellite.html

Comment: boah thx u very much
i will study ur answer but to be frank i want to do it within my program (code)

Comment: Ok, let me see to it and get back.

Comment: I found the **source** of ur listings an co.

http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2002/10/14/local2.htm?page=1

Comment: Consider using the macro TargetFrameworkSdkToolsDirectory, i.e.: $(TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory)resgen.exe